# How to mock std::something in Rust?

Tags: rust, mocking

Let's say I have this:

```
fn something(path: String) {
     let contents: Vec<u8> = std::fs::read(path);
     ...
}
```

How to mock the call to `std::fs::read()`? I know Rust doesn't support mocking out of the box, but even using libs like mockall, I can't see how this could be done.

These libs can mock traits and structs defined by me, because I can annotate those, but I don't see how this is supposed to work with the standard library modules.

Maybe mockall is not the right tool? What lib should I use?

Comment: Why would you need  to test reading a file? Just have the function take `Vec<u8>` instead.

Comment: I don't want to test reading a file. I want to test the logic inside this function, but there are dependencies such as this `fs::read()`.  This is only an example. What I'm looking for is a way to mock / fake / stub such dependencies, so I can test only the actual logic.

Comment: You can conditionally define a function (with a feature, or using `#[cfg(test)]` to be your mocked read if the condition holds and `std::fs::read` if it doesn't.

Comment: OK but does this mean that certain statements would require two definitions, one for the tests and another one for the real code? In other languages this is discouraged (eg: Node / JS / TS), but maybe it's OK in Rust. I'm not sure,  I'm new to Rust. It's just strange that there seem to be no easy way to mock 3rd party code. Anyway thx I look into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can conditionally select which `read` to use a few different ways.

### Mock function

In this example we define our own `read` only if tests are being built, otherwise we import `std::fs::read`.  Then we can just use `read` and know we'll get one or the other depending on whether tests are being built.

```
use std::path::Path;

#[cfg(not(test))]
use std::fs::read;

#[cfg(test)]
fn read(p: impl AsRef<Path>) -> std::io::Result<Vec<u8>> {
    todo!()
}

fn example() {
    let data = read("path").unwrap();
}

fn main() {
    example();
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    #[test]
    fn example() {
        super::example();
    }
}
```

### Conditionally invoke mock function at call site

In this case we use the `cfg!` macro to decide which function to call at the call site.  The optimizer will eliminate the other branch as dead code.

The disadvantage to this approach is having to duplicate the condition at every location you need to invoke `read`.  The advantage is it's very clear to the reader that mocking happens during tests without having to inspect the rest of the file to see what `read` is.

```
use std::path::Path;

fn mock_read(p: impl AsRef<Path>) -> std::io::Result<Vec<u8>> {
    todo!()
}

fn example() {
    let data = if cfg!(test) {
        mock_read("path")
    } else {
        std::fs::read("path")
    }
    .unwrap();
}

fn main() {
    example();
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    #[test]
    fn example() {
        super::example();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I accepted it. I will go with solution one. I would like to add, though, that even this doesn't seem to be ideal. I mean, yes you can do it this way, but this is not a mock. That means, you don't have any of the tracking functionality, like how many time the function was called, what args were passed etc. All the things mockall could do are missing. 
So using a real mock would ideal in my opinion, but this is also a valid solution and it works.